# How to make Group using Drag Drop using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I am working on a small project and that project include a functionality like below:

[image: Drag Drop then Make Group]

I have searched many articles but did not find which satisfy my requirement. All of theme are able to make **drag and drop** feature but none of them can make **group** like above example.

You are free to choose Javascript or Jquery or React for this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this now, you can add more style to it through ID's in CSS file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="example-parent">
  <h1>Re-arrangeable List</h1>
  <i><p>Change the order as you like by dragging</p></i>
  <div class="example-origin">
   <h3> <strong>LIST :-</strong></h3>
    <div
      id="draggable-1"
      class="example-draggable"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
      Item 1</div>
    <div
      id="draggable-2"
      class="example-draggable"
      draggable="true">
      Item 2</div>
    <div
      id="draggable-3"
      class="example-draggable"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
      Item 3</div>
    <div
      id="draggable-4"
      class="example-draggable"
      draggable="true"
      ondragstart="onDragStart(event);">
      Item 4</div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="example-dropzone"
    ondragover="onDragOver(event);"
    ondrop="onDrop(event);">
    ------Re-arranged List------</div>
</div>
<script>
function onDragStart(event) {
  event
    .dataTransfer
    .setData('text/plain', event.target.id);

  event
    .currentTarget
    .style
    .backgroundColor = '#7f5db8';
}


function onDragOver(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}



function onDrop(event) {
 const id = event
    .dataTransfer
    .getData('text');
 
 const draggableElement = document.getElementById(id);
 const dropzone = event.target;
 dropzone.appendChild(draggableElement);

  event
    .dataTransfer
    .clearData();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this solves your issue !!!
Happy Coding.

Comment: Drag the Item below the the title '------Re-arranged List--------'.